# Trouble writing to csv file with scrapy spider

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I wrote a simple spider and get an error when I try to write data to csv file. The error I get it ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'str'
When I try to print my results, everything seems fine, I just don't know how to write it to csv. I used scrapy crawl mmadness -o file.csv but nothing besides that error happens. Csv file is created but it's empty.
The problem is I'm not really sure what should I do with last statement or how do I return "table_rows" correctly.
Thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class MmadnessSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mmadness'
    allowed_domains = ['ncaa.com/standings/basketball-men/d1']
    start_urls = ['http://ncaa.com/standings/basketball-men/d1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.css('tbody tr')
        for row in rows:
            table_rows = row.css('td::text').extract()
            print(table_rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(table_rows)
```

you are printing your data while you should use :

```
yield(table_rows)
```

Comment: yield gives me en error: ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'list'

Comment: yes. its the base structure, use `yield {'table_row': table_row}

Comment: always pleasure.